# Get Parameters from Action<T>

Tags: c#, reflection, action

How do I get the parameters passed into an `Action<T>` ? The code example should highlight what I'm trying to achieve. Sorry that it's a little bit long.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.GetParams(x => x.Bar(7, "hello"));
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public void Bar(int val, string thing) { }
}

public static class Ex
{
    public static object[] GetParams<T>(this T obj, Action<T> action)
    {
        // Return new object[] { 7, "hello" }
    }
}
```

The only options that look vaguely useful are GetInvocationList(), Method and Target. But none of them seem to contain the data I'm after (I think it's because of the way I've declared the Action). Thanks

EDIT: It's not the types I want, it's the actual values - as noted in the commented bit of code.

Comment: @Henk, thats not so, only if it was foo.GetParams(x => x.Bar);

Comment: @richK: Are you after the captured vars?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why would you need to do this?

Comment: @Juliet - I know of various uses; the one I've used most often is for RPC interception.

Comment: I'm just toying with writing a Mocking Framework (for fun - not real life). This was just one of the ways I was trying to find which parameters are used. The syntax is the same as Rhino Mocks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do that, it should actually be an `Expression<Action<T>>`. Then it is a case of decomposing the expression. Fortunately I have all the code for that over in protobuf-net, [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net.Extensions/ServiceModel/Client/ProtoClientExtensions.cs) - in particular `ResolveMethod`, which returns the values in the `out` array (after walking any captured variables, etc).

After making `ResolveMethod` public (and removing everything *above* `ResolveMethod`), the code is just:

```
public static object[] GetParams<T>(this T obj, Expression<Action<T>> action)
{
    ProtoClientExtensions.ResolveMethod<T>(
        action, out Action ignoreThis, out object[] args);
    return args;
}
```

Comment: (I should note that `ResolveMethod` also returns the `MethodInfo` - i.e. the fact that you were calling `Bar`)

Comment: (oh, I also commented out the line about `RpcUtils`, which doesn't matter for this)

Comment: Thanks Marc, that's working wonderfully. I think I need to brush up on Expressions.

Comment: @RichK - well here's [my intro  to them](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/explaining-expression.html) ; and a few more [blog items](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/search/label/expression)

Comment: @RichK - other than it being possible to do this? OK; other impact: you can't use a lambda-expression-with-statement-body, i.e. a lambda with `=>{...}` (the braces being important). But if you need a delegate, just call `Compile()` on the expression.

Comment: Smashing thanks. I tried understanding them in C# in Depth, but to no avail - must be the way my brain's wired (or lack there of)

Comment: @RichK - actually, the **first** time I read about them in detail (in a pre-publication version of the same book), it made my head swim and eyes water. You need to start playing with them; they are actually easier and simpler than they sound. It is just **incredibly** hard to write about them in plain terms.

Comment: @MarcGravell your link no longer resolves to any specific code. Would you mind updating the link please.

Answer (score 5):

It should be something like this:

```
 public static object[] GetParams<T>(this T obj, Expression<Action<T>> action)
    {
        return ((MethodCallExpression) action.Body).Arguments.Cast<ConstantExpression>().Select(e => e.Value).ToArray();
    }
```

you should do some checking to verify that nothing invalid can sent into the action, as not everything is going to cast to a MethodCallExpression, but you should be able to follow from there

Comment: while valid for this case, in most real examples it is more complex - involving captured variables (and possibly multiple nested capture scopes), function/operator evaluations, etc.

Comment: @Marc I agree with you, I answered keeping it simple because I thought that aside of all the complexity to get the values he may have, what he really needs to get started is knowing that he needs to pass an Expression<Action<T>> and from there start playing with the different scenarios he might receive

Answer (score 3):

Your action `x => x.Bar(7, "hello")` can be rewritten as

```
void action(T x)
{
    return x.Bar(7, "hello");
}
```

It's clear now that `7` and `"hello"` are not the parameters of the action, only `x` is.

In order to get access to `7` and `"hello"`, you need an access to the expression, like what @Marc suggests. However it's not clear how your code should handle more complicated expressions, like `x => 1 + x.Bar(7, x.Baz("hello", x.Quux(Application.Current)))`.

Comment: re that last line; yes, that is the tricky bit; the code I cited *tries* to do as much as possible without having side effects, but with the example presented it will execute `Quux` and `Baz` etc, in order to try to get just plain values to report as the args.

Comment: I tried this (well, something similar) but the compiler doesn't like the 1+ bit, "Only assignment, call, increment etc".

Comment: @RichK: it depends a lot on what is the type of `x.Bar`. Adding 1 assumes that it's an `int`, but your actual type may be different.

Comment: @Marc: while it might be actually possible to get all the parameters of all the functions involved in the operation (that is, all the _leaves_ in the expression tree, if we consider addition a two-argument function), I really doubt that this makes sense. Therefore I am still sceptical about the original question; I think the OP perhaps needs something which is indeed simpler.

Comment: @Marc: IMHO in order to return the arguments without side effects, we have no other option as to return them as expression trees as well.