# Alter the parameters of an instance of an Action object

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

Say I have the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    SeveralCalls(() => CallWithParams("test"), 
                 () => CallWithParams("AnotherTest"));
}

public void SeveralCalls(params Action[] methodsToCall)
{
    foreach (var methodToCall in methodsToCall)
    {
        methodToCall();
    }
}

public void CallWithParams(string someValue, string otherValue = null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SomeValue: " + someValue);
    Console.WriteLine("OtherValue: " + otherValue);
}
```

**Is it possible to supply a value for the parameter `otherValue` for the calls to `CallWithParams` by only modifying the `SeveralCalls` method?**

I want to inject a value into the calls if it comes via the `SeveralCalls` method.

As a bit of background, I am working on code to call tabled paramed stored procedures (as a way to integrate my WCF Service into legacy code).  The call normally makes its own connection to the database, but I need to be able to group several calls in a transaction.

If I do that, then I need each call to use the same SqlConnection object.  The `SeveralCalls` method would allow me to group calls together, start a transaction, and (hopefully) pass the connection to the method that will actually make the call to the sproc.

Comment: You want to get parameters from `Action` ? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361314/get-parameters-from-actiont

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe this is possible. `() => CallWithParams("test")` is compiled to code that calls `CallWithParams("test", null)`, with both of those values hardcoded. There's no way (besides, potentially, some complicated reflection and/or IL emitting) to modify this in `SeveralCalls`.

If you could modify `Main` as well, this might be a good way to do it:

```
void Main()
{
    SeveralCalls("Some other string",
                 otherValue => CallWithParams("test", otherValue), 
                 otherValue => CallWithParams("AnotherTest", otherValue));
}

public void SeveralCalls(string otherValue, params Action<string>[] methodsToCall)
{
    foreach (var methodToCall in methodsToCall)
    {
        methodToCall(otherValue);
    }
}

public void CallWithParams(string someValue, string otherValue = null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SomeValue: " + someValue);
    Console.WriteLine("OtherValue: " + otherValue);
}
```

Or:

```
string otherValue = null;
void Main()
{
    SeveralCalls(() => CallWithParams("test", this.otherValue), 
                 () => CallWithParams("AnotherTest", this.otherValue));
}

public void SeveralCalls(params Action[] methodsToCall)
{
    this.otherValue = "Some other string";
    foreach (var methodToCall in methodsToCall)
    {
        methodToCall();
    }
}

// added static just to clarify that the otherValue here is separate from the 
// one in 'this'
public static void CallWithParams(string someValue, string otherValue = null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SomeValue: " + someValue);
    Console.WriteLine("OtherValue: " + otherValue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`Expression`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx). Everywhere you're currently using `Action`, use `Expression<Action>` instead. You can then inspect the expression object, create a new one and use the new one instead of the initial expression. Here's an example. Note the `ModifyExpression` method which verifies that the expression is a lambda that invokes the `CallWithParams` method. In this example, I'm looking at the parameters and if the second is missing or null, I programmatically create a new lambda expression with the second parameter equal to "overridden value". Note that I had to add the `null` values into the `CallWithParams` lambdas. Evidently you can't use expressions with default parameters, so I just had to give it the default value in the lambdas.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        SeveralCalls(() => CallWithParams("test", null),
                     () => CallWithParams("AnotherTest", null));
    }

    public static void SeveralCalls(params Expression<Action>[] expressions)
    {
        foreach (var expression in expressions)
        {
            var modifiedExpression = ModifyExpression(expression);
            var action = modifiedExpression.Compile();
            action();
        }
    }

    private static Expression<Action> ModifyExpression(Expression<Action> expression)
    {
        var lambda = expression as LambdaExpression;
        if (lambda == null)
            return expression;

        var call = lambda.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (call == null)
            return expression;

        var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("CallWithParams");
        if (call.Method != method)
            return expression;

        if (call.Arguments.Count < 1 || call.Arguments.Count > 2)
            return expression;

        var firstArgument = call.Arguments[0];
        var secondArgument = (call.Arguments.Count == 2 ? call.Arguments[1] : null);
        var secondArgumentAsConstant = secondArgument as ConstantExpression;
        if (secondArgumentAsConstant == null || secondArgumentAsConstant.Value == null)
            secondArgument = Expression.Constant("overridden value");

        var modifiedCall = Expression.Call(method, firstArgument, secondArgument);

        var modifiedLambda = Expression.Lambda<Action>(modifiedCall);

        return modifiedLambda;
    }

    public static void CallWithParams(string someValue, string otherValue = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeValue: " + someValue);
        Console.WriteLine("OtherValue: " + otherValue);
    }
```

Comment: Using expressions makes this possible, but it's still a *horrible* design practice.

Comment: I agree. There's probably a better way to do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

No. The `Action` objects your `SeveralCalls()` method receives are opaque. You cannot discover that their invocation code happens to call `CallWithParam()` without using reflection and CIL inspection and disassembly.

(Doing so would be rather complicated, and would also likely not be guaranteed to be portable since the details of how the C# compiler converts lambdas into anonymous types are not guaranteed not to change. In other words it is possible only by assuming non-public implementation details of the C# compiler.)

A better solution might be to put the `CallWithParams()` method inside a class that contains a field or property which you can change. Then you can set this field/property as desired, and any future calls to `CallWithParams()` will behave accordingly. The viability/sanity of this probably depends on what you're really trying to accomplish.

In my opinion, wanting to inject a parameter into lambdas is indicative of a flawed design, so if you can share more details about why you want to do this, maybe we can help find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, your method accepts a generic `Action`. There's no way for it to be sure that the code it's calling receives one or two parameters or what type that parameter is.

You could accept an `Action<string>` inside the `SeveralCalls`-method and then pass in that value in the invocation:

```
void Main()
{
    SeveralCalls(extra => CallWithParams("test", extra),
                 extra => CallWithParams("AnotherTest", extra));
}

public void SeveralCalls(params Action<string>[] methodsToCall)
{
    foreach (var methodToCall in methodsToCall)
    {
        methodToCall("some other param");
    }
}

public void CallWithParams(string someValue, string otherValue = null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SomeValue: " + someValue);
    Console.WriteLine("OtherValue: " + otherValue);
}
```