# How can I get these properties and values when I assign values to entitiy with Action<T>?

Tags: c#, orm

```
 public int Update(Action<T> updateAction, Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
```

This is the method I encapsulate to update the fields specified in the table，Notice the first parameter,which is a Action type. Just like this：

```
int effect = DaoPack.Sys_User_InfoDao.Update(m => { m.Email = "sample@abc.com"; m.FullName = "jim green"; }, m=>m.UserID==1);
```

I am in the bottom package method to analyze the Expression and then generate the corresponding SQL statement, but I cannot analyze Action, because it is not the expression tree, and I did not find a method of how to analyze the function of the sentence, so I want to ask what is the method to analyze the parameters of the Action type, because I want to get Email and FullName and their values for my generation Update SQL statement

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361314/get-parameters-from-actiont

Comment: No, I don't want to get the parameters of Action. I want to get the entity properties that are affected by Action

Comment: people don't seem to understand my poor English, the furthest distance in the world is I asked a question you don't know what I said, so I tell you the result I want, through this parameter m = > {m.Email = sample@abc.com; m.FullName = "Jim Green";}, I want to get a set of Dictionary<string, object>,just like this, key is "Email", value is "sample@abc.com"